# Create a table from a given array using inner.HTML

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm asked to create a table which can be sorted with a press of a button. The table is supposed to be created by a given array.

What I don't understand is how can I use an array loop inside a string so that the .innerHTML function would print the table body with the given object properties.

```js
    main = document.getElementById('body');
    listArray = [{name: 'Second', value: 2},{name: 'Fourth', value: 4},{name: 'First', value: 1},{name: 'Third', value: 3}];
    let showAll = () => {
      main.innerHTML = '';
      template(listArray);
    }
    let template = (arr) => {
      let loopArray = arr.forEach((item) => {return `<tr><td>${arr.name}</td><td>${arr.value}</td></tr>`});
      let html = `<table>
        <thead><th>Name</th><th id="value">Value</thead>
          <tbody>` + loopArray + `</tbody></table>`;
        main.innerHTML += html;
    }
    showAll();
```

Comment: I'm ignoring the sorting part for this question as I'm already informed about it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `map` instead of `forEach` so that the returned `<tr>` HTML string can then be joined together and set as the content of the table. You also need to refer to the properties of the `item` in the callback, not the `arr`.

```js
main = document.getElementById('body');
listArray = [{name: 'Second', value: 2},{name: 'Fourth', value: 4},{name: 'First', value: 1},{name: 'Third', value: 3}];
let showAll = () => {
  main.innerHTML = '';
  template(listArray);
}
let template = (arr) => {
  const tableContentHTML = arr
    .map((item) => {return `<tr><td>${item.name}</td><td>${item.value}</td></tr>`})
    .join('');
  let html = `<table>
    <thead><th>Name</th><th id="value">Value</thead>
      <tbody>` + tableContentHTML + `</tbody></table>`;
    main.innerHTML = html;
}
showAll();
```

```html
<div id="body"></div>
```

But concatenated HTML has security risks. If the input isn't known to be 100% trustworthy, a better approach would be to assign to the `textContent` of `<td>`s.

```js
const main = document.getElementById('body');
const listArray = [{name: 'Second', value: 2},{name: 'Fourth', value: 4},{name: 'First', value: 1},{name: 'Third', value: 3}];

let showAll = () => {
  template(listArray);
}
let template = (arr) => {
  main.innerHTML = '';
  const table = main.appendChild(document.createElement('table'));
  for (const item of arr) {
    const tr = table.appendChild(document.createElement('tr'));
    tr.appendChild(document.createElement('td')).textContent = item.name;
    tr.appendChild(document.createElement('td')).textContent = item.value;
  }
};
showAll();
```

```html
<div id="body"></div>
```